# Finding the coefficient of the particular solution of $2y'(x)-3y(x)=cos(2x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Having to solve $2y'(x)-3y(x)=cos(2x)$ We have to find a method such that $y_2(x)=acos(2x)+b\sin(2x)$ the given result is $a=3/25, b=-4/25$, why the hell did I found result absolutely different:

I did:

\begin{align*}2y_2'(x)-3y_2(x)&=cos(2x)\\
(2(2b\cos(2x)-2a\sin(2x))-3(a\cos(2x)+b\sin(2x))&=cos(2x)\\
(4b-3a)\cos(2x)-(2a+3b)\sin(2x)&=cos(2x)\\
\end{align*}

Therfore

\begin{cases}
4b-3b&=1\\2a-3b&=0
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
a&=-3/2b\\
4b+9/2b&=1
\end{cases}

\begin{cases}
b&=2/17\\a&=...
\end{cases}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake appears on the sceen-copy below. Also, check the wording for typo of sign.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, by the way your articles on regression sounds very interesting!

Comment: You are welcome. Eventually, do not hesitate to contact me for further information.